# How would I return x and y from different classes to main in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse

How would I return my x and y variable into main in order to perform the addition?
Thanks in advance for the help!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calling {

    public static int x;
    public static int y;

    public static void num1() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        x=scanner.nextInt();    
    }

    public static void num2() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a second number: ");
        y=scanner.nextInt();    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){     **//place to return variables.**

        num1();
        num2();
        System.out.print("The sum of the two numbers is: " + (x+y));
    }
}
```

Comment: it is unclear what you're trying to do. Please clarify or rephrase your question.

Comment: He's _trying_ to learn Java.  He _needs_ to put down the computer and go read a book...

Comment: Have you considered getters and setters? That would be a much more elegant solution if you asked me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be using static data members or methods - those should only be used when the member of method applies to *all* instances of a class.

In this case the only static method should be `main` and that should only create a single *instance* of the current class.  `main` should almost never do any real work - although in this trivial example I suppose an exception could be made.

You should ideally also only create a single `Scanner` object - the `Scanner` class is perfectly capable of reading a continuous stream of numbers without you needing to create a new one over and over for each number to be read.

In the code below I just create one and use it twice directly.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calling {

    public calling() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.print("Please enter a number: ");
        int x = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Please enter a second number: ");
        int y = scanner.nextInt();

        System.out.println("The sum of the two numbers is: " + (x + y));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new calling();
    }
}
```

Alternatively the scanner object could have been stored as a member variable, as in this example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class calling {

    private Scanner scanner = null;

    private int getInt(String prompt) {
        System.out.print(prompt);
        return scanner.nextInt();
    }

    public calling() {
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in)
        int x = getInt("Please enter a number: ");
        int y = getInt("Please enter a second number: ");
        System.out.println("The sum of the two numbers is: " + (x + y));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new calling();
    }
}
```

Comment: Bad answer. You are not really answering the question and nitpicking without a good explanation. IMO there is no general rule against static fields in a static test class where no instance is made, nor is it clear why he should not make two Scanner instances. OTOH you don't mention his poorly chosen class name (should start with upper case and preferable refer to a thing i.e. 'Caller') and method name (should refer to an activity i.e. 'call').

Comment: @AdriaanKoster there were so many things wrong with the original code that picking on the class and method names really would have been nitpicking.

Comment: @AdriaanKoster since you asked - 1. repetition, 2. no encapsulation, 3. `num1` and `num2` setting static members instead of returning values. 4. the stuff you mentioned

Answer (score 3):

```
public static int getInput() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    return scanner.nextInt();
}

public static void main(String[] args){     
    System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
    int x = getInput();   

    System.out.println("Please enter a second number: ");
    int y = getInput();

    int sum = x + y;
    System.out.print("The sum of the two numbers is: " + sum);
}
```

or a more OO (Object Orientated) approach might look like

```
public class Calculator {

private Scanner scanner;

public Calculator() {
    scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
}

public int getInput() {
    return scanner.nextInt();
}

public int add(int x, int y) {
    return x + y;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {     
    Calculator calculator = new Calculator();

    System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
    int x = calculator.getInput();   

    System.out.println("Please enter a second number: ");
    int y = calculator.getInput();

    int sum = calculator.add(x, y);
    System.out.print("The sum of the two numbers is: " + sum);
}
```

Note that [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java) state classes should have uppercase first letters.

Comment: Did you mean (x+y) instead of (x, y) in the first example?

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the return types of num1 and num2 to int and save the result of both functions in variables in main. Then perform your addition with the new variables, or just change the addition to (num1() + num2()).

In addition to that, grab a book and try to understand how to use functions because what you're asking is pretty basic.

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking for a way to return the values to main function, read the code below

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static int x;
    public static int y;

    public static int num1() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
        x=scanner.nextInt();
        return x;    
    }

    public static int num2() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a second number: ");
        y=scanner.nextInt();
        return y;    
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){    

        int a = num1();
        int b = num2();
        System.out.print("The sum of the two numbers is: " + (a+b));
    }
}
```